# How to mark api-created Okta users as being provided by Active Directory

Tags: okta, okta-api

We’re currently running the Okta Active Directory agent in order to import our users into Okta.

I'd like to replace this with a custom built process that imports users into a new internal database, for other user-management-related activities, whilst also adding those users to Okta.

Creating the user in Okta is easy, but I also need to get the user's "provider" set to ACTIVE_DIRECTORY, so that Okta delegates authentication to Active Directory.

The documentation (http://developer.okta.com/docs/api/resources/users.html#provider-object) says that the User's Provider field is read-only.

How can I set it?

Answer (score 1):

While you cannot directly manipulate the credential object you can leverage other features available to achieve the desired result.

1. Create a group in Okta and configure it as a directory provisioning group. From the designated group select 'Manage Directories' add the desired Directory and follow the wizard to completion.
2. Add the created users to the group (using the API)

Answer (score 0):

You unfortunately cannot set this property as we do not allow the creation of Active Directory users through the public API at this point.

If the purpose of the new process is simply to enrich the user's profile, can't you not achieve this by letting the AD agent sync the users and enrich the profile directly through the API?